# Can I detect if the event is saving entry?

Tags: craft3, php, modules, events

I have been implementing my own module like this;

```
protected function myFunction()
{
    Event::on(
    ElementQuery::class,
    ElementQuery::EVENT_BEFORE_PREPARE,
    function(Event $event) {

        if ($event->sender->elementType === 'craft\elements\Asset')
        {
            // DO SOMETHING...
```

However, I do not want to perform this function when an entry is saved. It seems that `EVENT_BEFORE_PREPARE` is triggered when I save an entry. So, is it possible to detect if the event is saving an entry or not?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you better use this kind of a event for your custom logic?

```
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\ModelEvent;
use yii\base\Event;

....

    Event::on(
        Entry::class,
        Entry::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
        static function (ModelEvent $e) {
          
        }
    );
```

or

```
Event::on(
    Element::class,
    Element::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    static function (ModelEvent $$e) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

Comment: Actually, the function on `EVENT_BEFORE_PREPARE` has already been made, but a problem was found. So, I would like to prevent the function only if `$event` is saving an entry.

Comment: Not really sure what you want to do, but try looking at these options -> https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/events.html#event-code-generator
https://i.imgur.com/zGP07xe.png
Perhaps your problem is that every time you save the entry, you re-save the assets